# Cannot access a disposed object VC++ VS2017 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, tfs, dispose

I am trying to open a project (mapped locally from tfs ). The project is in Visual C++.

I have tried many forums and still no success. I am getting following error.

[image]

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017. I tried to modify and add all the vc++ project components. I installed all necessary vc++ components and still, I am getting this error.

Other c# projects work perfectly fine. (Meaning: VS is not corrupt, it works fine!) I simply can't open *.vcproj*. 
Should I be installing visual studio 2012? ( one of my colleagues is using 2012 and it works like charm! )

Comment: _Other c# projects work perfectly fine_, you're not opening a C# project, have you installed the components for VC++ and not just C#?

Comment: Yes. I have installed all the components for vc++

Comment: Saying Other c# projects work perfectly fine, I mean to say that my VS is not corrupted. @JSteward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this could help somebody. I followed the following steps to solve this:

1. Installed visual studio 2010 which has all SDKs to support VC++
   projects
2. Now I can open .vcproj in VS2017 as it has all available SDKs (from
   2010 installation) which will ask you to update your project version. Feel free to choose the latest version.
3. Still, I got an error of ***"Missing afxwin.h"*** which is in MFC/ATL
   support components [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46798473/1162201). I installed using the link provided
   in source.
4. No Success yet. Geeting error of ***MFC does not support WINVER less than 0x0501.  Please change the definition of WINVER in your project properties or precompiled header.*** Solved by changing WINVAR in **StdAfx.h**

   > `#define WINVER 0x0501`

   ***Note 0x501 is Windows XP support. 0x600 is Vista, 0x601 is Windows 7***
5. You may change configuration. Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28077594/1162201)
6. Compiled Successfully!